# Use of log_bin_trust_function_creators in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, security, data-integrity

What is the use of `log_bin_trust_function_creators`? 
Also, Is the value of the parameter dynamic? 
Will it change if I restart my MySQL service?

Comment: In Aurora it is a dynamic parameter, and no restart is required.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This variable controls whether binary logging should trust the stored function creators for not to create stored functions that will cause unsafe events. Eg. having UUID functions.

This has been explained well in documentation:

> When you create a stored function, you must declare either that it is
>   deterministic or that it does not modify data. Otherwise, it may be
>   unsafe for data recovery or replication.
>
> By default, for a CREATE FUNCTION statement to be accepted, at least
>   one of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA must be specified
>   explicitly. Otherwise an error occurs:
>
> `ERROR 1418 (HY000): This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL,
>   or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled
>   (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators
>   variable)`
>
> To relax the preceding conditions on function creation (that you must
>   have the SUPER privilege and that a function must be declared
>   deterministic or to not modify data), set the global
>   log_bin_trust_function_creators system variable to 1.

Reference: [mysql-documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html) (read this as it explains with example.)

About your second question, if it's dynamic and will it change if you restart server:

- Yes it is a dynamic variable.
- The variable will change upon restart, if you do not update the config to reflect the change.

Reference: [mysql-documentation-again](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_bin_trust_function_creators)

Comment: does it take a boolean value? Right it is is set to TRUE for me.. does that mean it is '1'?

Comment: `mysql> select  if(1 is true,'TRUE','FALSE')\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
if(1 is true,'TRUE','FALSE'): TRUE
`

Comment: Ok I understand that. But is it necessary to change it to '1' particularly for that parameter? Now since I set it as TRUE, when I restart the mysql service will it change again

Comment: That's right! So to make it persistent you should put the same configuration value in your my.cnf file as well.

Comment: So if i change it when the db is running the change will be in effect immediately and besides that i will have to change it in config file for it to take effect if my mysql restarts. Right?

Comment: That's right @tesla747,
Run on mysql prompt: 
`set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;`

- This will set it globally in mysql.

Add in my.cnf: 
`log_bin_trust_function_creators=1`
- This will make the change permanent.

Comment: Any impacts on production db if I change set it globally when the prod is running?

Comment: No. (meeting min chars to post the comment)

Comment: Haha okay. Right now the parameter is showing the value as ON. Recently my server got restarted but the value is still ON. It should change right since I have not set the same in config file.

Comment: 1, TRUE, ON -- these are usually synonyms in setting variables.  Ditto for 0, FALSE, OFF.

Comment: @mysql_user should log_bin be enabled for log_bin_trust_function_creators to be in effect?

Comment: @tesla747 yep... it applies when binary logging is enabled.

Comment: @mysql_user mind helping me out in enabling binary logging?

Comment: @mysql_user http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26025/discussion-between-mysql-user-and-kristofer-gisslen this would be a better place?

Comment: Do you know why `CONTAINS SQL` is not part of the allowed options? It [seems more restrictive than ` READS SQL DATA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) so it should be "safer"?!